# Stuck in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

When I try to zoom  using the scrollweel in viewport,I get teleported to another galaxy, the only way to get back is by pressing (number pad . ). Help?

Comment: didn't the number pad. help? that's what fixes this problem for me in blender.

Comment: The problem was that i couldn't zoom, I could get back, but with no use, I imported the object's in another project and it worked.

Comment: weird, things like this just happen, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If "another galaxy" is still the milky way :) and your zooming is WAY too fast: Some mice have buutons to increase/decrease the amount of . Check you mousedriver for the according seetings (windows) or sometimes imwheel and devilspie go nuts on Linux. In that case restart both services.

Comment: Idk what happend, it only happens to that project, I just started another one, and imported my objects there.